# Facebook App opens from IBAction but Twitter Doesnt?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

Im able to open the facebook app with the code below but not twitter.  What is wrong with the twitter code that twitter will not open like facebook? Nothing happens at all when i try my button to open twitter

```
- (IBAction)Facebook:(id)sender {

    NSURL* facebookURL = [ NSURL URLWithString: @"https://facebook.com/myProfile" ];
    NSURL* facebookAppURL = [ NSURL URLWithString: @"fb://profile/123456789" ];
    UIApplication* app = [ UIApplication sharedApplication ];
    if( [ app canOpenURL: facebookAppURL ] ) {
        [ app openURL: facebookAppURL ];
    } else {
        [ app openURL: facebookURL ];
    }

}
- (IBAction)Twitter:(id)sender {

    NSURL* twitterURL = [ NSURL URLWithString: @"http://twitter.com/myProfile" ];
    NSURL* twitterAppURL = [ NSURL URLWithString: @"twitter://‎" ];
    UIApplication* app = [ UIApplication sharedApplication ];
    if( [ app canOpenURL: twitterAppURL ] ) {
        [ app openURL: twitterAppURL ];
    } else {
        [ app openURL: twitterURL ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the twitter URL schemer you must add a `user` when calling the native app permitter like so....

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name=PROFILE"]]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name=PROFILE"]];
}
else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=PROFILE"]];

}
```